# How do i show the percentage number of a pie chart in turtle graphics inside the chart?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

My assignment requires me to print out from a text file, the difference in population between 2018 and 2019 of each continent on pie chart.

I have already done the pie chart.

However I would like to add the % of each section of the piechart into the piechart itself.

Currently, I have the percentage number outside of the piechart. How do i do this?

Currently my percentage number is outside of the bar chart, together with the continent name :

```
def operation_1():
    divisions = [(('Asia',x1_p,"%"), x1), (('North America',x2_p,"%"), x2), (('South America',x4_p,"%"), x4), (('Africa',x5_p,"%"), x5), (('Europe',x6_p,"%"), x6), (('Oceania',x7_p,"%"), x7)]
    COLORS = cycle(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'lightgreen'])
    RADIUS = 200
    CONTINENT_RADIUS = RADIUS * 1.35
    PERCENTAGE_RADIUS = RADIUS * 1.35
    FONTSIZE = 15
    FONT = ("Arial", FONTSIZE, "bold")

    total = sum(fraction for fillcolor, fraction in divisions)
    screen = turtle.getscreen()
    screen.title("Pie Chart")
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-400, -400, 400,400 )
    piechart = Turtle()
    piechart.penup()
    piechart.sety(-RADIUS)
    piechart.pendown()
    piechart.speed(0)

    for fillcolor, fraction in divisions:
        piechart.fillcolor(next(COLORS))
        piechart.begin_fill()
        piechart.circle(RADIUS, fraction * 360 / total)
        position = piechart.position()
        piechart.goto(0,0)
        piechart.end_fill()
        piechart.setposition(position)

    piechart.penup()
    piechart.sety(-CONTINENT_RADIUS)

    for continent, fraction in divisions:
        piechart.circle(CONTINENT_RADIUS, fraction * 360 / total / 2)
        piechart.write(continent, align="center", font=FONT)
        piechart.circle(CONTINENT_RADIUS, fraction * 360 / total / 2)

    piechart.hideturtle()


    x = input("Please input x to initiate another operation: ")
    if x.lower() == 'x':
        screen.clearscreen()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to ajust your `PERCENTAGE_RADIUS` and set it when you write your text. Full example with random percentage:

```
from turtle import *
from itertools import cycle

continent = ['Asia', 'North America', 'South America', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
percentage = [10, 5, 20, 10, 25, 5, 25]
divisions = [('{:s} {:d}%'.format(c, p), p) for c, p in zip(continent, percentage)]

def operation_1(divisions):
    COLORS = cycle(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'lightgreen'])
    RADIUS = 200
    CONTINENT_RADIUS = RADIUS * 1.35
    PERCENTAGE_RADIUS = RADIUS * 0.8 # Set your radius here
    FONTSIZE = 15
    FONT = ("Arial", FONTSIZE, "bold")

    total = sum(fraction for fillcolor, fraction in divisions)
    screen = getscreen()
    screen.title("Pie Chart")
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-400, -400, 400,400 )
    piechart = Turtle()
    piechart.penup()
    piechart.sety(-RADIUS)
    piechart.pendown()
    piechart.speed(0)

    for _, fraction in divisions:
        piechart.fillcolor(next(COLORS))
        piechart.begin_fill()
        piechart.circle(RADIUS, fraction * 360 / total)
        position = piechart.position()
        piechart.goto(0,0)
        piechart.end_fill()
        piechart.setposition(position)

    piechart.penup()
    piechart.sety(-PERCENTAGE_RADIUS)

    for continent, fraction in divisions:
        # Use the text radius here
        piechart.circle(PERCENTAGE_RADIUS, fraction * 360 / total / 2)
        piechart.write(continent, align="center", font=FONT)
        # Use the text radius here
        piechart.circle(PERCENTAGE_RADIUS, fraction * 360 / total / 2)

    piechart.hideturtle()


    x = input("Please input x to initiate another operation: ")
    if x.lower() == 'x':
        screen.clearscreen()


operation_1(divisions)
```

Result :

[image]